# How to send data (selected radiobutton) in R to googlesheets for every new user?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyjs

I wish to take feedback from the user asking "Did you like the song suggestion?" (Options will be "Yes" or "No"..) for every new user and send this data to googlesheets. On every new user, I want the googlesheet to get updated instead of creating new sheet for new user. How do I do it? Please help.

ui.r

```
This is in main panel
radioButtons("feedback","Did you like song suggestion?",list("Yes"="Yes","No"="No"),""),              
actionButton("increment","Submit Feedback"), uiOutput("count"),
```

server.r logic

```
# A reactiveValues object holds the value of the counter
    values <- reactiveValues(i = 0)
    # Print the value of the counter stored in values$i
    output$count <- renderUI({
      h4(paste0(values$i,"are the no of users who have liked song suggestion"))})
    # The observers re-run the code whenever the button is clicked
    # Use isolate to avoid getting stuck in an infinite loop
    observe({
      chosen <- input$increment
      isolate(values$i <- values$i + 1)
    })
```

Comment: What is the code you're using to send the data?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik  I dont know how do I send the selected radiobutton to the google sheet in R shiny. I want to know the code in R